# how to handle html anchor tag specified within CDATA tag in ftl(freemarker)

Tags: java, freemarker

I need to handle html anchor and target tags coming inside [CDATA] tag. My freemarker version is 2.3.18.

Please advise how to handle this using freemarker escape or no escape tag. When i tried adding escape tag, value is not reaching the ftl. Not sure if i am doing it wrong.

```
    <#assign cDataStart="<![CDATA[">
    <#assign cDataEnd="]]>">
    <tr class="planHeading">
     <#assign xlist = plan.column> // plan.column is list of strings
      <#list xlist as x>
        <h2 id="planMed">
            ${cDataStart}${x?replace("<br>", cDataEnd+"<br />"+cDataStart)}${cDataEnd}   // x consist "You pay INR 0.00 <br>**For more information regarding, please click <a href=https://www.example.com/a.pdf target=_blank>here</a>."
         </h2>
      </#list> 
    </tr>
```

Expected Output for ${x} :

```
"You pay INR 0.00 <br>**For more information regarding, please click here"
```

Current Output :

```
"You pay INR 0.00 <br>**For more information regarding, please click <a href=https://www.example.com/a.pdf target=_blank>here</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `${x?no_esc}`.

Alternatively, you can turn off the auto-escaping for the whole template, adding

```
<#ftl autoesc=false>
```

in the first line.

See http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html for more details.

Comment: When i add ${x?no_esc}, the value is not reaching the ftl and hitting exception. Issue is bit different, understood it bit late. I have modified question and desc accordingly. Please advise.